# Create new variables inside a loop, that were not previously defined

Tags: python, loops

for example,
in this loop:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in lst:
    print i
```

Instead of just printing i, is there a way to asign i to a new variable each time?
so that I would get something like: item1=1 item2=2 item3=3 and so on.

Or is there a way to create new variables without knowing in advace how many I would need?

For example, a variable for each item in the list lst, or any other list (with any other len()) that the user gives.

for all of you who are wondering. the point of doing this is being able to call the variables later. my code searches for segments within a list that fit to a certein criteria, and I want to be able to reach the segments later, or at least for the user to be able to. I am new to programming, so if you have a better way to do that please tell me.

Comment: `item1, item2, item3, ... = lst`

Comment: That won't work, @AshwiniChaudhary. OP doesn't know the number of items in advance

Comment: Don't, you really don't want to do that. Just [keep your data out of your variables](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: One thing you should ask yourself is... **why** do you want to create new variables? And explain us

Comment: I mean, yeah, you can create variables on the fly... but what for? The rest of your code CANNOT know about them in advance, either

Comment: I guess you are new to programming, you have learnt some basics and you think you are OK with variables but not OK with others like lists and dictionaries. A good programmer uses appropriate tools for his needs. If your elements are in a list, it is not wise to separate them using single variable for each of them, since you practically break the relationship between them.

Comment: +1 for "if you know of any better ways, please tell me"

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. You already have the data stored. Instead of doing `item1`, just do `lst[0]`.

`item2` -> `lst[1]`

`item3` -> `lst[2]`

`itemn` -> `lst[n-1]`

Edit 2:

Try this:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def split_condition(x):
        return (x == 3)
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5], split_condition)]
[[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [3], [4], [3], [5]]
```

Comment: grate! thanks thats a good idea! Ill put all the segments the loop finds in a previously defined list and reach them this way later.

Comment: @user3316932 No problem! I wouldn't usually say this about an answer, but in this case this is the definitive correct way of doing things.

Comment: no wait, on second look that wont work... I would have to partition this list later in some way. it seems like the wrong way to go.

Comment: @user3316932 I can guarantee that dynamically creating variables is not what you want to do. Could you give some detail about how you want to partition the list?

Comment: as I said, my loop finds segments in a given list, according to a certain criteria. theoretically I would want to recieve a list of those segments.so I could maybe append the segments the list finds into a previously defined list, but then I would just get a single list of items with no differentiation between the segments.  I would have to think of a whay to partition it the right way and make sublists.

Comment: in response to your edit, I need the second type of prtitioning.

Comment: I tried it and realised it's not what I needed. but I already fixed the problem. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to partition the data according to a certain criteria. Let's say that you have a function `figure_out_class` that gives you a description for the class that you data falls on. Then you can use a dictionary to do this:

```
partitions = {}
for i in lst:
    key = figure_out_class(i)
    if key not in partitions:
        partitions[key] = []
    partitions[key].append(i)
```

This "is the key there already?" can be avoided populating the dictionary first using the classes you know you'll need, or using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
partitions = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst:
    key = figure_out_class(i)
    partitions[key].append(i)
```

For a practical example, say that you want to classify numbers as `odd` or `even`:

```
def figure_out_class(number):
    return ("odd" if number % 2 else "even")
```

Applying that function to the previous piece of code gives you:

```
>>> partitions['odd']
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> partitions['even']
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score -1):

You COULD do:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in xrange(len(lst)):
    exec('item%d=%d' % (i, lst[i]))
```

which will create variables item0, item1... all having values equal to respective positions in the list.

I don't see the point of all this though :)

Comment: Why people answer to questions when they don't understand what the author asked?

Comment: [Unadorned exec, execfile() and friends](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/doanddont.html#unadorned-exec-execfile-and-friends)

Comment: In Python 2, if `exec` is used inside a function disables (important) optimisations. In Python 3 (where `exec()` is a function indeed), you *cannot* set local names at all, so this code wouldn't work. That's all quite apart from this being a *terrible* idea in the first place.

Comment: @MaximeLorant - I think we both understood 100% what the author is requesting. You seem to have a problem with the actual request. These answers give exactly what is requested.

Comment: @Lix: no we don't. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem also, see my previous comment.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - woah... totally forgot about that meta post! I guess you've convinced me :) Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: thank you! the point is being able to call these variables later.